# how to join a string with comma after splitting it: Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that splits a string on commas does some function on each split and returns all results. I want the results to be returned back with the commas again

**example**

```
original_string ="five, negative four, three"
```

I run some function on it and I get

```
def challenge1(original_string):
    #some code
    return new_string
```

I have tried

```
print(new_string.splitlines())
#below is what I get. How can I get them on the same line to start with so I add commas to them later
['5']
['-4']
['3']
```

Below is the result I get

```
5 
-4
3
```

The result I need is

```
5, -4, 3
```

I have been trying a lot of options with the `.join(", ")` but it still returns on a new line how do I get the above result

Answer (score 1):

You should call the `str.join()` method with a list as the argument:

```
", ".join('5\n-4\n3\n'.splitlines())
```

This returns `'5, -4, 3'`.

This means that the return statement of your `challenge1` function should instead be:

```
return ", ".join(new_string.splitlines())
```

Comment: return new_string ", ".join('5\n-4\n3\n'.splitlines())

Comment: That's not how you apply my suggestion. I've updated my answer with an example of how you can modify the return statement of your function.

Comment: `[',5'] 
[',-4']
[',3']` and they are all on new lines not in the same lines. If it helps The results are generated by a forloop before and returned on  `new_string`

Answer (score 0):

Well it was easier than I expected it to be

```
def challenge1(original_string):
    #some code
    return new_string

print(new_string, end=", ")
```